# StartActivity start after few seconds when admob interstitial Ad close

Tags: android, admob

In `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent` of Interstitial Ad start new Activity using `startActiviy(Intent(...))` in normal case ad show and close the inter ad the new Activity start normally.

The issue is when Inter Ad show then I press home button and open app again from recents then I press on inter ad close the Ad close but the `new Activity start after few seconds` why.

here is onAdDismissedFullScreenContent code

```
 override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));
        finish()

}
```

Comment: There is an issue with Interstitial Ad's callback, at least on Debug builds. The callback is fired after a delay of few seconds.

Comment: I have the same issue the callback is delayed after ad shown , did you find solve for it ?